# MySQL - Update "status" on a list of "codes" in my table

Tags: mysql

Hi I have the following table structure:

```
code     status
ABC123   0
ABC124   0
ABC125   0
```

I have a list of around 200 specific codes that I need to set the status to 1.

What command would I run in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Do you have this list of codes in a specific format? I think I would write them into a table and use a subquery for the update statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `WHERE IN` to select those codes to update.

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET status = 1
WHERE code IN ('ACB123', 'ABC125', ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try in your /phpmyadmin and select your database and hit below query in SQL tab:

```
UPDATE `tablename` SET `status` = '1'
```

Comment: I need to do this on a specific set of codes not all codes

Comment: Use where condition like UPDATE `tablename` SET `status` = '1'  where `code` = 'ABC123'

Comment: If change status in multiple field use IN like UPDATE tablename 
SET status = '1'
WHERE code IN ('ACB123', 'ABC125', ...)